# QueryList not updated with dynamic component

Tags: angular

I have a parent component which can have multiple instances of the same child component. The tricky part here is that an instance of the child component is available at init and based on certain logic within child component I am using a output event emitter to regenerate another child component from the parent component. However, when saving I just see the first instance of the child component which I had put in my html template and not the dynamically generated one. I did see other similar questions but none seem to had the same problem. What am I missing here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE - start**

Added a plunker to demonstrate the issue if someone wants to play around and find the cause

https://plnkr.co/edit/FW49ztzsg5uyXF7DtHDY?p=preview

**UPDATE - end**

**Parent Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef, ViewChild, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component( {
    selector: 'parent-cmp',
    entryComponents: [ChildComponent],
    template: `
        <child-cmp (onSomeSelectionChange)="onSomeSelectionChange($event)"></child-cmp>
        <div #childCompSection></div>
        <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
    `
} )
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild( 'childCompSection', { read: ViewContainerRef } ) childCompSection: any;
    currentComponentHolder: any;
    @ViewChildren( ChildComponent ) childComponents: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

    constructor( private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // do some stuff to load initial view, nothing done using childComponents
    }

    onSomeSelectionChange( someValue ) {
        if ( someValue !== 3 ) {
            let componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory( ChildComponent );
            this.currentComponentHolder = this.childCompSection.createComponent( componentFactory );
            this.currentComponentHolder.instance.onSomeSelectionChange.subscribe( data => this.onSomeSelectionChange( data ) );
        }
    }

    // Need all child components (which includes dynamically generated components) here 
    save() {
        console.log(this.childComponents); // This just prints the child-cmp object that is already added not the ones that are dynamically added via ComponentFactoryResolver
    }

}
```

**Child Component**

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component( {
    selector: 'child-cmp',
    template: `
        <div>
            <select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="showNumberField($event)">
                <option value="0">Select...</option>
                <option value="1">Add...</option>
                <option value="2">Subtract...</option>
                <option selected value="3">End</option>
            </select>
            <div *ngIf="showField">
                <label>Number:</label><input type="number" [(ngModel)]="numValue">
            </div>
        </div>
    `
} )
export class ChildComponent {

    @Output() onSomeSelectionChange = new EventEmitter<Lookup>();
    selectedValue: number;
    numValue: number;
    showField: boolean = false;

    showNumberField(value) {
        if(value !== 3) {
            showField = true;
        }
        this.onSomeSelectionChange.emit( value ); // This does work fine and another instance of the child component is generated from parent component but QueryList in parent component does not get updated
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12818

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a confirmation from the [Angular chat forum](https://gitter.im/angular/angular) that @ViewChildren/@ViewChild can only read elements which are already available in the view. Since, dynamic components are not available during view init, I had to maintain a list of all such dynamically generated components to keep track of them.

Comment: How did you maintain that list? I have a bunch of dynamic component instances, can create as many instances as needed, or delete as many, and still trying to find a way to get a hold of the current list of these instances on click action. `@ViewChildren` does not work for me, always returns empty.

Comment: You have to dynamically generate components using ComponentFactoryResolver, there are tons of examples if you google. Now when you create using the resolver you will get an object of componentHolder (define the type as any), and you can get the component instance by componentHolder.instance, and then add this to an array of such components which you now can maintain. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

I came across the same issue and found that you can subscribe to the query list changes which will fire if you add or remove an element. Hopefully will help someone else down the line...

```
@ViewChildren(MyComponent) myComp: QueryList<MyComponent>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myComp.changes
            .subscribe((queryChanges) => {
                // Do something
            });
}
```

Comment: Was this recently added in an version upgrade? Just want to make sure if this was available from the beginning or was just a recent addition. Also, did you try to replicate the issue I have mentioned with the above? I am not too sure this will resolve the issue I stated.

Answer (score 2):

After all your child components `ngAfterViewInit` method will execute

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

 ngAfterViewInit(){

     ///////////////// your operations
 }
```

So you cannot perform operations in `ngOnInit`

Comment: I am not using childComponents in ngOnInit, it is used in save() which is called on a button click from the parent component which is after view init. And as I said, all my child components are not available after view init as they are dynamically generated. Have modified sample as well to reflect where I am looking for all the child components

Comment: It is super important to note that the code must go in ngAfterViewInit *and not* ngOnInit

Comment: @DavidPoxon are you asking me something?

Comment: @Aravind Just reaffirming your contribution. I scratched my head for a long while as I was including code in ngOnInit, not ngAfterViewInit.

Answer (score 2):

Use @ViewChildren like you did:

```
@ViewChildren("elements")
private elementsArray!: QueryList<any>;
```

When you need the update:

```
this.elementArray.changes
        .subscribe((queryChanges) => {
            ...
        });
```

Finally, to avoid errors and detect changes, in the constructor:

```
private ref : ChangeDetectorRef
```

And then below ngOnInit(),

```
ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.ref.detectChanges();
}
```

Works for me, gl :)

Comment: this.ref.detectChanges(); after content checking seems like a very bad idea for change detection

Answer (score 0):

I think this [Angular bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12818) is still not fixed. I had to manually remove the element, something like below, similarly it can be updated manually.

```
@ViewChildren('configElement') public configValues: QueryList<ConfigValueComponent>; (Declaration)
this.configValues['_results'].splice(data.index, 1); (remove deleted element)
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ViewChildren` and `@ContentChildren` will update for dynamic content, but getting there is tricky.

The issue goes like this:

- In a `@Component`, the model `T[]` updates
- A `*ngFor` binding updates
- `QueryList` remains unchanged even though `*ngFor` changed

When you think about it, it makes sense. The CD-run that updated that `*ngFor` has already passed. To get around it, you will need to make Angular run CD again. Let's add some steps:

- In `@Component`, the model `T[]` updates
- In `@Component` we run `this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();` to flag the view as dirty
- In `@Component` we run `this.zone.run(() => Promise.resolve());` to tick the app
- A `*ngFor` binding updates
- `QueryList` remains unchanged even though `*ngFor` changed
- The `Promise` fires and a second CD-run starts
- The `QueryList` updates since the view was flagged as dirty