# Access dynamically loaded child component instance

Tags: angular, viewchild, angular-dynamic-components

```
@ViewChild(ComponentType) comp!: ComponentType;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log('ComponentType instance', comp);
}
```

To get hold of a child component's instance, I know that `ViewChild` can be used as shown above. It works for statically added components, but if I use it on a dynamically added component as demonstrated [here on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s8qqpg-bad87a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fad.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), I get undefined on `ngAfterViewInit`.

What's the proper way to get hold of a dynamically loaded child component's instance?

Comment: So you try to access a grandchild in your parent? Not possible as far as I know. What exactly are you trying to do with your grandchild?

Comment: You need to post your html

Comment: In my actual case, I want to call an instance method, @MoxxiManagarm. Actually it doesn't work even for direct child. Let me edit to demo it.

Comment: Edited to query direct child, @MoxxiManagarm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. Angular doesn't get children created dynamically with ViewChild/ViewChildren. See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45771 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/43957857/4472932.

But you can save the created childs in a service as example. The component self is `const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent<AdComponent>(adItem.component);` the **componentRef**.
So a children of ViewChildren/ViewChild is the same like componentRef.

Greetings, Flo